# python - read strings printed by php

Tags: python, python-requests

I have php code that takes a string and prints it with the code below.
When I open the html code in the browser, I can see the tag with the string but when I use the Python module requests and I print the html code with content, it doesn't read the tag with the string tooked by php code.

```
if( array_key_exists( "name", $_GET ) && $_GET[ 'name' ] != NULL ) {
echo '<pre>Hello ' . $_GET[ 'name' ] . '</pre>';
}
```

Python code

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
t = 'This is a test'
cookie = dict(cookies_are = 'security=low; PHPSESSID=4g1fc3fv5gde1fi3lpbk0tccl3')
url = 'http://192.168.178.81/vuln/vulnerabilities/xss_r/?name='+t

response = s.get(url, cookies = cookie)

page =  response.content.decode('utf-8')
if t in page:
    print "Found it"
else:
    print "Not Found"
```

Comment: Can you provide your Python code? Maybe you have to add `name` to headers/body of get method.

Comment: Try to do it this way `if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])){
echo '<pre>Hello ' . $_GET[ 'name' ] . '</pre>';}`

Comment: Hi,

I'm not PHP programmer but according to https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php, the $_GET reads the query variables from URL. In your example the part responsible for it is `?name=` part of `url` variable. Can you try diffrent `t` like `t='test`` without any spaces? It might problem with url encoding.

Comment: it's the same. My goal is to write a python script that tests xss payloads on DVWA